# How can I use Kingfisher to set the image on a map annotation view?

Tags: swift, mapkit, kingfisher

I want to have images downloaded by kingfisher and set as the `image` of my `AnnotationView`. The problem is that Kingfisher only seems to work on `UIImageView`'s and the `AnnotationView` doesn't seem to expose its.

So one approach would be to use Kingfishers download mechanism to retrieve the image and set it by myself:

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url) { result in 
    // Do something with `result`
}
```

But I'd rather want Kingfisher to set the image because with this approach I'd lose some of Kingfishers features (e.g. placeholder image).

How can I get a hold of the AnnotationView's ImageView?

Comment: Image you fetch from URL is like this "https://example.com/image.png"

Answer (score 0):

I've added an imageView to my annotationView. It works with great success.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 42))
annotationView?.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: I've done that too in the end, but struggled because I had to set the annotation view's size by hand then (before it was not visible): view.frame = CGRect(...)